# The numbers on online dashboard differs from the downloaded CSV in Google Analytics

Tags: csv, google-analytics, report

I have a "very simple" problem.. When i make a custom report in a filtered view in my Analytics account, the numbers i see on the online dashboard differs from the ones, that are downloaded directly from that report into Excel .csv.. We do cross-domain tracking, and the purpose of the filtered view is to see the domains in the view (basic, suggested by analytics help).

What could be the problem? Do any of you suffer from the same problem? This is very annoying, because we can't trust our numbers..

Thank you in advance,
Adam

Comment: How old is the data you are extracting?

Comment: Try not selecting anything under 3 days old.  See if the numbers match then.

Comment: The bigger the interval i see, the more the mistake it does.. If the interval is under 50 days, then it's usually correct, but there is no guarantee... I don't see the point in this.. i just want to see that very numbers online in csv..

Comment: Data under 48 hours old isn't done processing yet so it could cause problems if you extract that.  Also the CSV export has never been knowing for being actuate.  In my experience.

Comment: If i get this month's data till today, it's correct.. if i get the datas from 1st of May till today, it's correct.. if i get them from 1st of April till today.. it's all messed up.

The question is.. which one is correct? The csv one or the online dashboard? What should i use instead of? API requests?

Comment: Dashboard is correct.  try running your requests against the API here http://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/explorer/

Comment: Thank you. This gets the same wrong numbers, that the simple csv.

Comment: How much data do you have could be sampling level.

Comment: Plenty of data.. plenty of sources, some goals.. 200k sessions/month average

Comment: Then it could be an issue with sampling level  https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel

Comment: HEY!:) This should be that... if i set the online report to "Faster response, less precision", then it matches the CSV data.. Is there any options that it can download to CSV with the other option "Slower response, greater precision"? This would solve the problem!

Comment: No not with the CSV and not with the query analyzer either.   But a request to add it has been made.

Comment: Okay, many thanks, if you write it to an answer, i can accept it as a solution, because now i can provide clarification to client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue may be [sampleing level](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/reference#samplingLevel)

```
samplingLevel=DEFAULT 
Optional.Use this parameter to set the sampling level (i.e. the number of sessions used to calculate the result) for a reporting query. The allowed values are consistent with the web interface and include: •DEFAULT — Returns response with a sample size that balances speed and accuracy.
•FASTER — Returns a fast response with a smaller sample size.
•HIGHER_PRECISION — Returns a more accurate response using a large sample size, but this may result in the response being slower.
If not supplied, the DEFAULT sampling level will be used.See the Sampling section for details on how to calculate the percentage of sessions that were used for a query.
```

There is no way to test if this is your problem, because at this time you cant set sampling level when extracting as CSV nor can you set it in the query explorer.  But I wrote an application that will extract information into CSV and allows you to select sampling level.  [Daimto - Google Analytics Export](http://www.daimto.com/google-analytics-import/) you can use that to test if this is the problem or not.

Comment: Thank you! From the fact, that, if i manually set the sampling for the online dashboard, and the numbers i see are matching with the downloaded CVS, i assume that the problem is indicated by this. However, i'm going to try your application, but i can't know on business computer.